# Swift - Multiply values from two UITextFeild's

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to calculate two values from two UITextFields. What I did was made the `answerScreen` equal to the `valueOne` which I turned into an `Int` and `valueTwo` which is supposed to be the opposite of an var with the `!`. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // The answer will be here
    @IBOutlet weak var answerScreen: UILabel!
    // The first number
    @IBOutlet weak var valueOne: UITextField!
    // The second number
    @IBOutlet weak var valueTwo: UITextField!
    // The equals button
    @IBAction func calculateValues(sender: AnyObject) {
        answerScreen.text = valueOne.text.toInt() * valueTwo!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the opposite of an var"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let result = (valueOne.text.toInt() ?? 0) * (valueTwo.text.toInt() ?? 0)
answerScreen.text = "\(result)"
```

Will convert the text field values to `Int` or use `0` if the conversion failed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain to me why you turned it into a constant and what the "??" means?

Comment: I assigned it to a constant to make the code more readable (than if I'd put the computation inside the string interpolation). `??` is the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124). `a ?? b` uses `a` if it is not `nil` or `b` otherwise. It's a fallback in case `.toInt()` returns `nil` because the user did not enter a valid number.

Answer (score -1):

One Can try

```
var temp =  (firstTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue * (secondTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue
```

For setting value to UILabel

```
self.resultLable.text = String("\((firstTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue * (secondTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue)")
```